# How do I handle overlapped/stacked suppressive fire damage?

Tags: combat, damage, cyberpunk-2020

The rules about suppressive fire in the core rulebook explain that you can use suppressive fire from 2 guns, simply add the rounds of both to the save formula (Save = number of rounds / width of fire zone in meters).  If the enemy fails their save, then they will take 1D6 rounds in random locations.

But what if you have 2 guns that do different damage?  How, then, would you determine which gun's damage gets applied?

Further building on this - what if you have multiple players creating a fire zone in the same area?  The RAW say

> ...teams should coordinate their actions and fire at the same time, placing the maximum number of rounds into the fire zone.

If the enemy gets hit, then which gun's damage gets applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Quick answer:** The randomess in this is so high that a bit more won't do damage, roll even/odd to find out.

**House rule answer:** In **Cp2020** there are tons of house rules because of its ambiguity, but is also part of its *magic*, I usually make people do REF+Athletics check (classic difficulty becomes the minimum to-hit) vs all attacks, also full-auto gets a bonus for this (in classic rules you get -1 for each 10 bullets), on a fail you got hit by 1D6 bullets (double of burst)

The house rule answer is to show you that in **CP2020** the RAW is so vague that this question probably gets some different answers... and all of them would seem right.  Maybe chat with players to see how they see alternate rules before applying them.

Comment: So... in other words this wasn't actually covered by the book.  I guess this is the best answer, but I'm disappointed by it.  The spirit of a house rule, for me, is that house rules are mods to an existing system, building on it or changing it to add a challenge or make things more fun.  They shouldn't be bugfixes.  A good analogy is if I buy a backpack, I don't mind modding its appearance to have buttons and patches, but I'll be rather upset if I get home and realize it doesn't have a zipper.  

I was kinda hoping I just missed a ruling on this somewhere.  Ah well.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird, but given that there is no supplement that clarifies the rule... let's hope all this would be fixed in CYBERPUNK RED (soon I hope)